# is it posible to accurately place a circle relevant to real life object using arcore?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Using arcore and/or sceneform, would it be possible to place circles accurately on a real life object. Lets say i had a real world table and a known set of coordinates where small ( 10mm ) AR "stickers" need to be placed. They could be on the top/side/underside of the table and need to be placed accurately to the mm. I am currently solving this problem with a number of fixed mounted lasers. would this be possible to accomplish using arcore on a mobile device - either a phone or AR/smart glasses? Accuracy is critical so how accurate could this solution using arcore be ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find that current AR on mobile devices would struggle to meet your requirements.

Partly because, in my experience, there is a certain amount of drift or movement with Anchors, especially when you move the view quickly or leave and come back to a view. Given the technologies available to create and locate anchors, i.e. movement sensors, camera, etc it is natural this will not give consistent millimetre accuracy.

Possibly a bigger issues for you at this time is Occlusion - currently ARcore does not support this. This means that if you place your renderable behind an object it will still be drawn in front of, or on top of, the object as you move away or zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple markers or AR "stickers" your solution will be pretty precise considering your location of your circles will be calculated relative to those markers. Image or marker based tracking is quite impressive with any Augmented Reality SDKs. **However**, having these markers 10mm can cause problems for detection of markers. I would recommend creating these markers using `AugmentedImageDatabase` and you can specify real world size of the images which helps for tracking of these images. Then you can check if ARCore can detect your images on the table. ARCore is not the fastest SDK when it comes to detecting images but it can continue tracking even markers are not in the frame. If you need fast detection of markers i would recommend Vuforia SDK.